# Geodjango point in polygon join without loop

Tags: geodjango

```
class Location(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.PointField()


class Boundary(models.Model):
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField()
```

I want query every Location and include its containing Boundary. The boundaries don't overlap so each Location is contained in exactly one Boundary.

My SQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Location l
  INNER JOIN Boundary b on ST_CONTAINS(b.geom, l.coordinates)
```

I would like to avoid iterating over my boundaries individually, e.g:

```
for boundary in Boundary.objects.all():
    Location.objects.filter(coordinates__within=boundary.geom)
```

Seems like an obvious use case, but I haven't seen any solutions to it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using a subquery as per the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) in the Django docs.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
sq = Boundary.objects.filter(geom__contains=OuterRef("coordinates"))
points = Location.objects.annotate(boundary=Subquery(sq).values("pk"))
```